# Think Time in Visual Studio Test Project

Tags: performance, webtest

We have a requirement as below:

We need to test N number of load of users for a single page aspx web application. If 100 load users we don't want 100 users to hit the web site concurrently.

I've setup the web performance test project with Think Time 60sec. However when I run this as load test the request per seconds is more than 7. Could anyone help what's the correct way to setup such that 100 concurrent users doesn't hit the website but randomly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the "user pace" test mix.
How many times a single user should visit this page?
Set the value on the test mix, and on the scenario properties window set the "Apply Distribution to Pacing Delay" to true.

Tal